# Sending and Receiving Bitmaps per TcpClients

Tags: vb.net, tcp, bitmap, client

So, I'm currently making a LAN-Streaming-Program, which should record the screen of the streamer and display it at the viewer's screen.
My problem is, that when I try to convert the received ByteArray-Image to an image, it gives me a `System.ArgumentException`.

Here's the code for sending:

```
Private Sub SendFrame(ByRef IP As String, ByRef Frame As Bitmap)

    FrameClient = New TcpClient(IP, 7009)

    Dim FrameStream As New MemoryStream
    Dim FrameBytes() As Byte

    Frame.Save(FrameStream, ImageFormat.Bmp)
    FrameBytes = FrameStream.GetBuffer()

    SendMessage(IP, "NextFrameSize;" & LocalIP & ";" & FrameBytes.Length)

    Using NS As NetworkStream = FrameClient.GetStream
        NS.Write(FrameBytes, 0, FrameBytes.Length)
        NS.Close()
    End Using

End Sub
```

And here for receiving:

```
Private Sub CheckForFrames() 'This Sub is called everytime the viewer receives the size of the next Bitmap.

    If FrameListener.Pending = True Then

        FrameClient = FrameListener.AcceptTcpClient
        Dim ImageBytes(NextFrameSize) As Byte

        FrameClient.GetStream.Read(ImageBytes, 0, NextFrameSize)

        Dim MS As New MemoryStream(ImageBytes)
        StreamBox.Image = Image.FromStream(MS, False)
        MS.Close()

        FlushMemory()

    End If

End Sub
```

I would be thankful for any answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim ImageBytes(FrameClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
```

This returns the size of te buffer, not the actual size of the bitmap:

> The size of the receive buffer, in bytes. The default value is 8192
>   bytes.

So, `ImageBytes` will probably be 8192 bytes, not the size of your bitmap.

You might want to send the size before you send the bitmap data, and on the receive side read in the size first to initialize your `MemoryStream`.

Comment: That didn't work either. I'm now sending the size of the byte array, saving it in a variable. Then I send over the image, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Since the buffer is (by default) 8kB, you might need to `.Read()` multiple times until you have the full image.

Comment: I somehow managed to do it, but it only shows some of the taskbar, and not the whole screen. The rest of the image is black. I'll edit the code in my post so you can see.

Comment: It seems as if you image size (buffer) is ok now, but didn't read all the RGB pixels into it.

Comment: Okay, I know what the problem is now. 1920 x 1080 Pictures are too big to send them 30 times per second. I tried the Jpeg-Format, but it's still too big. I will work on an Image-Resize-Feature, which will (hopefully) decrease the file size. But thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: That's a lot of data indeed. In that case, usually only the changed (and compressed) pixels are sent over the network. I.e. a mask is used, and then compressed to .png for example. That way there's no loss of quality.